# systemd-resolved switching DNS after timeout

Tags: networking, dns

I have a local DNS server to resolve names on my LAN, but systemd-resolved only uses it for a few minutes before switching to a different DNS server.

```
/var/log/syslog
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Transaction 29195 for <feeds.propublica.org IN AAAA> scope dns on wlp2s0/*.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 29195.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Using DNS server 192.168.1.250 for transaction 29195.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Sending query packet with id 29195.
...
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Timeout reached on transaction 29195.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Retrying transaction 29195.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Switching to DNS server 192.168.1.1 for interface wlp2s0.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Cache miss for feeds.propublica.org IN AAAA
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Transaction 29195 for <feeds.propublica.org IN AAAA> scope dns on wlp2s0/*.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 29195.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Using DNS server 192.168.1.1 for transaction 29195.
Mar 11 16:38:06 allen-dell systemd-resolved[20854]: Sending query packet with id 29195.
```

Is there a way to tell systemd-resolved to not switch?

---

### update

I had tried to make 192.168.1.250 the only NS, but it seems like the dhcp in my router (D-Link DIR-860L) is explicitly adding its gateway to the lease (because I have not specified it manually).

```
systemd-resolve --status
Link 3 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.250
                      192.168.1.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      local

dhclient-XXX-wlp2s0.lease
lease {
...
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.250,192.168.1.1;
```

Comment: Usually, there is a reason for systemd-resolvd to switch to a different DNS-Server. In your log it looks like the reason is a timeout from the DNS-Server at 192.168.1.250. Did you test that DNS server with a tool like dig or nslookup to see if it works and can provide an ipv6 address?  `nslookup -type=any feeds.propublica.org 192.168.1.250`or `dig @192.168.1.250 feeds.propublica.org ANY` would be a start.

Comment: That DNS server does work when I query it directly, so I'm fairly confident it's not a `bind` problem.  I'm very new to `systemd-resolved` so I just need to figure out how to get it to "prefer" my DNS whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, but it might not prevent it from also accepting the on proposed by the DHCP-Server.